# I keep getting this error: TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not tuple

Tags: python, object-detection

I am trying to do this tutorial: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1d8PEeSdVlP0JogKwkytvFeyXXPu_qfXg?usp=sharing#scrollTo=sDixMreeUS_9

and this is https://github.com/mjpramirez/Volvo-DataX the repository in GitHub

So when I am trying to run the model I kept getting this error and I already find which file has this error and this is where the problem:

```
unmatched_trackers = []
  for t,trk in enumerate(trackers):
    if(t not in matched_indices[:,1]):
      unmatched_trackers.append(t)
```

I tried to replace 1 with 0 but still not working.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your problem. For example, can you share more information on the error and what `trackers` and `matched_indices` are?

Comment: WHERE do you get that error?  There are dozens of files in that repository.

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace the `sklearn.utils.linear_assignment_.linear_assignment` function by the `scipy.optimize.linear_sum_assignment` function by importing like `from scipy.optimize import linear_sum_assignment as linear_assignment`.

The difference is in the return format: `linear_assignment()` is
returning a numpy array and `linear_sum_assignment()` a tuple of numpy arrays.
You obtain the same output by converting the output of `linear_sum_assignment()` in array and transpose it.

```
 Example: 
  matched_indices = linear_assignment(-iou_matrix)
  matched_indices = np.asarray(matched_indices)
  matched_indices = np.transpose(matched_indices)

  OR 

matched_indices = np.array(list(zip(*matched_indices)))
```